# why two JRE are installed while installing java

Tags: java

I installed jdk 1.8. While installing, two JRE were copied to my computer:

The first is inside JDK folder and the second is outside .What's the purpose of having two JRE in the same Operating System .

Isn't one JRE enough to handle all requests .

[image]

[image]

Comment: I thought one was the JRE and one was the JDK?

Comment: The "Public JRE" is for the browser plugin. I would disable that.

Comment: no both are JRE's @MadProgrammer

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> Private vs. public JRE - Installing the JDK installs a private Java SE
>   Runtime Environment (JRE) and optionally a public copy. The private
>   JRE is required to run the tools included with the JDK. It has no
>   registry settings and is contained entirely in a jre directory
>   (typically at C:\Program Files\jdk1.6.0\jre) whose location is known
>   only to the JDK. On the other hand, the public JRE can be used by
>   other Java applications, is contained outside the JDK (typically at
>   C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.6.0), is registered with the Windows
>   registry (at HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\JavaSoft), can be removed
>   using Add/Remove Programs, might or might not be registered with
>   browsers, and might or might not have java.exe copied to the Windows
>   system directory (making it the default system Java platform or not).

Source: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/install-windows-189425.html

Comment: can we use same JRE for both condition?then that type of problems we going to face ? @tarek

Comment: I don't think that because they are not same. The private JRE has no registry setting and exclusively for the JDK to run the tools, where public JRE is the one, which other Java applications uses.

Comment: I understand what you mean. Yes, its true that JRE is Java Virtual Environment, where the java program runs on. But the private and public JRE has different uses. For example, if you want to debug java system classes, then the private JRE is required, which indicates, you can't handle everything with the public JRE. Again, the private JRE is not associated with registry, so external java programs can't use it directly. That means, one single JRE is not enough to handle all requests, at least the java language designers did not design in that way.

Comment: Not all machines are Windows.  The JDK installed alone on various operating systems is fully sufficient to launch any Java app or app server.  In Windows, jdk-8u60 **minus** the public JRE does install registry entries to `HKLM/SOFTWARE/JavaSoft/Java Development Kit/1.8` so Eclipse IDE finds it just fine.  Tried JMX Console, it finds things just fine.  Get the feeling the only thing the public JRE is for on Windows is the browser.

Answer (score 0):

Browser will run from java/jre
Java running from java/jdk/jre
When we install internet Explorer it will download jre
JDK/jre wil be use by the command line tool because command line default java home will be set to jdk with it looks for jre and run the java.exe inside the jdk/jre